# Springboot Hikari Config - Connection Timeout

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hikaricp

I am load testing a REST endpoint in a Springboot application that get products data from MySQL database. Under low traffic it seems to be working fine, but if I send 100 concurrent requests, the calls starts getting slower and I see logs full of the following error

`o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.`

`org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection] with root cause java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms`S

My hikari config looks like below

```
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query=SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=50
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=1800000
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=20
spring.datasource.hikari.validation-timeout=3000
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=60000
```

All the tables are linked with each using foreign key, index etc. so shouldn't be time consuming. The table has only around 2000 records and is linked by a couple of small size tables.

I have tried different configs but nothing seems to make it work under load. Please guide me what I am doing wrong.

Many thanks

Comment: Your pool size is 50 and you have 100 concurrent requests.

Comment: So if I can expect 500 concurrent users, I will have to set maximum-pool-size to 500 i.e. 1 pool for each request ?

Comment: You can set it to 500 but you have to monitor the connection pool during the load test and then use the max number